# Understanding Monadic Fibonacci

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I am learning haskell and learning monads. I've watched and read various tutorials and coded some simple examples for state monad, however I am not able to understand the following piece of code (taken from Haskell Wiki):

```
import Control.Monad.State
fib n = flip evalState (0,1) $ do
  forM [0..(n-1)] $ \_ -> do
    (a,b) <- get
    put (b,a+b)
  (a,b) <- get
  return a
```

My question boils down to the following:

1. What is going inside the first statement of the inner do, i.e what does `(a,b)<-get` result into. What will be the values of `a` and `b` for some concrete example.
2. Why would you want to use the state monad over here?

Comment: As far as 2) goes, you...wouldn't, in real code, it's just a toy example.

Answer (score 4):

In this example, the state is a pair containing the previous two numbers generated in the sequence. This is initially `(0, 1)` provided to `evalState`.

The type of `get` is `MonadState s m => m s` so in the inner `do` block

```
(a, b) <- get
```

fetches the state pair and binds `a` and `b` to the first and second elements respectively. The state is then updated in the following `put`.

The state will therefore be:

```
(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 5), ...
```

The outer

```
(a, b) <- get
return a
```

unpacks the final state value and returns the first element.

Answer (score 3):

First lets make clear the Fibonacci algorithm being used. The idea is to start with the tuple `(0, 1)`, then find the next as `(1, 0 + 1)`, the next as `(1, 1 + 1)`, `(2, 2 + 1)`, `(3, 3 + 2)`, and so on. Generally, the step is `\(a, b) -> (b, a + b)`. You can see that in these tuples are the Fibonacci numbers.

> What is going inside the first statement of the inner do, i.e what
>   does (a,b)<-get result into?

Haskell does not have statements, only expressions.

`y <- x` is not a complete expression. It is similar to `x >>= \y ->`.

```
y <- x
m
```

Is a complete expression and is equivalent to `x >>= \y -> m`. A line `n` not of the form `y <- n` is equivalent to `_ <- n` (excluding `let` lines and maybe some others I forget).

Using this we can desugar do-notation.

```
fib n =
  flip evalState (0, 1)
  ( forM
      [0..(n-1)]
      (\_ -> get >>= (\(a, b) -> put (b, a + b)))
    >>= (\_ -> get >>= (\(a, b) -> return a)))
  )
```

Now it is just about understanding `>>=`, `return`, `get`, `put`, and so on.

State is actually just functions of the type `s -> (s, a)`. They take an initial state and yield the next state plus some other value.

`m >>= n` a.k.a. "bind" has the type `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Then, if our Monad is `State s`, this is the same as:

```
m >>= n ::
     (     s -> (s, a))
  -> (a -> s -> (s, b))
  -> (     s -> (s, b))
```

The `a` returned by `m` has to be passed to `n`. What else can we guess? We expect the state to pass along as well, so the state returned by `m` must be passed to `n` as well. The function `m >>= n` must return the state and value that `n` returns. We then know how to implement bind:

```
m >>= n = uncurry (flip n) . m
```

`return :: Monad m => a -> m a` which is then equivalent to `return :: a -> s -> (s, a)`:

```
return = flip (,)
```

`get :: State s s` is equivalent to `get :: s -> (s, s)`:

```
get = join (,)
```

`put :: s -> State s ()` or `put :: s -> s -> (s, ())`:

```
put s _ = (s, ())
```

`evalState :: s -> State s a -> a` or `evalState :: s -> (s -> (s, a)) -> a`:

```
evalState s f = snd (f s)
```

You can expand all the definitions and see exactly what is happening in the example. Just the intuitions should suffice though.

```
forM
  [0..(n-1)]
  (\_ -> get >>= (\(a, b) -> put (b, a + b)))
```

We don't care about having the numbers `0` to `n - 1` so the first argument is dropped. `get` retrieves the current state, then `put` writes the new state. We do this `n` times.

```
>>= (\_ -> get >>= (\(a, b) -> return a)))
```

We don't care about the accumulated value (which is unit) and so the first parameter is dropped. Then we get the current state and project just the first element of the pair. This is the final answer we're looking for.

```
flip evalState (0, 1) …
```

Finally we run starting from the initial state `(0, 1)`.

There are some cleanups we can make to this implementation. First, we don't care about the range `[0..(n-1)]`, we just care about repeating an action `n` times. A more direct way to do this is the following:

```
replicateM n (get >>= \(a, b) -> put (b, a + b))
```

The result is a list of unit which is unused, so a more efficient version is:

```
replicateM_ n (get >>= \(a, b) -> put (b, a + b))
```

There is already a function for the common pattern of `get` followed by `put` named `modify`, which is defined as `\f -> get >>= put . f`. Therefore:

```
replicateM_ n (modify (\(a, b) -> (b, a + b)))
```

Then there is the part:

```
>>= (\_ -> get >>= (\(a, b) -> return a)))
```

Any time we don't care about the previous result we can use `>>`.

```
>> get >>= (\(a, b) -> return a))
```

This is:

```
>> get >>= return . fst
```

`m >>= return . f` simplifies to `fmap f m`:

```
>> fmap fst get
```

Now we have, in total:

```
fib n =
  evalState
  (  replicateM_ n (modify (\(a, b) -> (b, a + b)))
  >> fmap fst get
  )
  (0, 1)
```

We might also use, for comparison:

```
fib n =
  fst
  ( evalState
    (  replicateM_ n (modify (\(a, b) -> (b, a + b)))
    >> get
    )
    (0, 1)
  )
```

And then because I am silly:

```
fib =
  fst
  . flip evalState (0, 1)
  . (>> get)
  . flip replicateM_ (modify (snd &&& uncurry (+)))
```

> Why would you want to use the state monad over here?

You wouldn't. This is clear because we only use the state value; the other value is always unit and discarded. In other words, we only need `n` (i.e. which Fibonacci number to find) at the beginning and afterwards we only need the accumulated tuple.

Sometimes you think to have a string of compositions like `h . g . f` but you want to send two arguments through instead of just one. That is when `State` may be applicable.

If some functions read and some write the state (the second argument), or do both, then `State` fits the bill. If there are only readers then use `Reader` and if there are only writers then use `Writer`.

We can alter the example to make better use of the State Monad. I will make the tuple disappear!

```
fib =
  flip evalState 0
  . foldr (=<<) (return 1)
  . flip replicate (\x -> get >>= \y -> put x $> x + y)
```

Answer (score 2):

So the docs state: `get :: m s  -- Return the state from the internals of the monad` (see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html)).

But I remember very well that when I tried to wrap my head around the State Monad this didn't help me a lot.

I can only recommend playing around with `:i` and `:t` in ghci and test out different sub-expressions. Just to get a feel for it. A bit like this:

```hs
 import Control.Monad.State.Lazy 

 runState (get) 0
 runState (get >>= \x -> put (x+1)) 0
 :t return 1 :: State Int Int
 runState (return 1) 0
 runState (return 1 >>= \x -> (get >>= \y -> return (x+y))) 0 

 -- Keeping a pair of (predecessor/current) in the state:
 let f = (get >>= (\(a,b) -> put (b,a+b))) :: State  (Int, Int) ()
 runState (f >> f >> f >> f >> f >> f) (0,1) 

 -- only keeping the predecessor in the state:
 let f x = (get >>= (\y -> put x >> return (x+y))) :: State Int Int
 runState (return 1 >>= f >>= f >>= f >>= f >>= f >>= f) 0
```

Also play around with `modify`, `runState`, `evalState`, `execState`.